# Where is the crontab group under CentOS?

Tags: cron, centos

I'm writing a script to harden the Linux servers.

However I can't find the crontab under CentOS. Any idea where is such group under CentOS and Redhat?

BR

MG

Comment: there is no such thing as a cron user. Cron is a daemon

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps